# Tempフォルダ内にあるファイルをApplicationSurpportフォルダにコピーできない

Tags: swift

ReplayKitで録画したデータは、recorder.stopRecording(withOutput: outURL)を使用すると指定したURLにダイレクトに保存できるようなのですが、ApplicationSurpportフォルダなどで試しても保存できず、Tempファイルにしか保存できないように見えます。

参考；[URL of screen recording from ReplayKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966724/url-of-screen-recording-from-replaykit)

そこで、以下のコードのように、Tempフォルダ内にあるファイルをApplicationSurpportフォルダにコピーしようとしてもエラーになってしまいました。

Tempフォルダ内のファイルというのは、外部にコピーできないものなのでしょうか？

Tempフォルダにファイルが存在すること自体は確認できるのですが、コピー結果がエラーになってしまいます。

```
func copyTempVideoToApplicationFolder(srcURL:URL)
{
    guard let applicationURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else{ return }
    let dstURL = applicationURL.appendingPathComponent("recordedVideo.mp4")
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: srcURL.path)
    {
        print("tempファイルが存在するよ")
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path)
        {
            //すでにファイルがあれば削除
            do
            {
               try FileManager.default.removeItem( atPath: dstURL.path )
            }
            catch {print("remove_error")}
        }

        do
        {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
        }
        catch{
            print("Unable to copy file: copyTempVideoToApplicationFolder")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("tempファイルが存在しないよ")
    }
}
func endRecordingReplayKitVideo(stopHandler: @escaping ()->Void)
{
    // 録画中じゃないと終了しない
    guard self.recorder.isRecording else { return }
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *)
    {
        if let outURL = self.tempURL()
        {
            self.recorder.stopRecording(withOutput: outURL) { (error) in
                stopHandler()
                guard error == nil else{
                    print("Failed to save ")
                    return
                }
                if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outURL.path)){print("exists")}else{print("not exists")}
                //application surpport folderへコピー
                self.copyTempVideoToApplicationFolder(srcURL:outURL)
            }

        }
    }
 }
func tempURL() -> URL? {
    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
        
    if directory != "" {
        let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    } 
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2つ大きな問題点があります。

1. `FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`で返されるのはApplicationディレクトリであり、ApplicationSurpportディレクトリではありません。
2. Sandbox保護されたアプリ用のファイル領域には、限られた少数のディレクトリ(`Documents`のみ?)しか存在せず、それ以外のディレクトリは、ディレクトリ作成の命令を実行しない限り存在しません。

今回はあまり大きな問題ではないかもしれませんが、せっかくdo-try-catchで受け取れるエラー情報を黙って無視してしまうのはやめた方が良いでしょう。

以下のようなコードを試してみてください。

```
    func copyTempVideoToApplicationFolder(srcURL:URL) {
        guard let applicationSupportURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {return}
        //保存先のディレクトリが存在しなければ作成する
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: applicationSupportURL.path) {
            //簡略化のためエラーは無視
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: applicationSupportURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        let dstURL = applicationSupportURL.appendingPathComponent("recordedVideo.mp4")
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: srcURL.path) {
            print("tempファイルが存在するよ")
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path) {
                //すでにファイルがあれば削除
                do {
                   try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: dstURL.path)
                } catch {
                    print("remove_error: \(error)")
                }
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to copy file: copyTempVideoToApplicationFolder: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("tempファイルが存在しないよ")
        }
    }
```

`recorder.stopRecording(withOutput: outURL)`は試していませんが、保存先のディレクトリを上記のように作成しておけば、保存できるかもしれません。

Comment: 問題なく保存できました。ありがとうございます！